Understanding data.table left join
I read in the data.table documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf the following:
X[DT, on="x"] # left join

And, using this example:
A <- data.table("a"=1:4, "b"=12:15)
B <- data.table("a"=2:3, "b"=13:14)
B[A, on='a']

I get:
   a  b i.b
1: 1 NA  12
2: 2 13  13
3: 3 14  14
4: 4 NA  15

I would like to understand what is happening under the hood here. What is the order of things?
In my head we are working inside the scope of B in the join above, and what is happening is that we are for every row in A checking if there is a match in B on the on criteria. If there is a match, or multiple matches, this/these index/indeces are "stored", and we move on to the next row of B and so on.
But I just don't understand what happens when there is no match. Why would we "bring" a row from A (first and last row) when we are operating within the scope or context of B?
Is a join like this more than just a matching of whatever is in on in order to return some index/indeces which then are applied to B?
UPDATE: We need to understand what is going on when doing these operations. To me, not understanding what is going on behind the scenes of these operations is highly problematic. The just use merge.data.table instead just goes to show what big problem this is. There has supposed to be a vignette about joins, but for years nothing has happened (source: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2181).
For example, I have never seen anybody actually explain what is going on in this example:
A <- data.table("a"=1:4, "b"=12:15)
B <- data.table("a"=c(2:3,6), "b"=13:15)
# A left join B
B[A, on='a']
# and this is also A left join B, where last match duplicates are kept
A[B, on = 'a', bb := i.b]

What, on, earth, is, happening?

Is it that you don't under stand the difference between a left/right join and an inner join? What is surprising to you about the output you are getting? With a left/right join, if there is no match you pull in an NA value. That's why rows 1 and 4 have an NA value in the B column. There was no match in B for that value of a. (It's confusing that the column names similar to the data.table names).

I think it's a misunderstanding of data.table's [ join syntax. "In my head we are working inside the scope of B in the join above" doesn't sound right to me about "inside the scope of B". B[A, on='a'] is equivalent to merge(A, B, on = 'a', all.x = TRUE), which is to say a left join where all rows from A will be included, and any matching rows from B will be included. If you change your example so that B$a has values not in A$a, this will be apparent.

As an explanation of the syntax (which I also found unintuitive when I was learning), I would suggest extending the standard data[rows, columns] syntax to think of B[A, on = 'a'] as the first argument in brackets A, answering the question of "What rows do you want? All the rows in A.", as A is in the "rows" argument position. (Of course, if you only want matched rows you can add the argument nomatch = NULL, see ?data.table for more details.)

@MrFlick I understand SQL and all these types of joins. I just want to understand what is happening under the hood. Just how are things done, if you know what I mean

@GregorThomas ah, I see, I changed B$a to contain values not in A$a, and like you said, those rows/values are not brought forward in the join.
Yes, this syntax is driving me mad. What is the point of having this bracket syntax if it has nothing to do with data[rows, columns] like you point out?
Ok, If I think my way of thinking about B[A, on = 'a'] as what rows do I want? all the rows in A, how do I relate this to B? It is so unintuitive to me.

I mostly just use data.table::merge() because it's clearer to me. You don't have to use [ to join if you don't like the syntax.

@GregorThomas well, the reason that I want to understand this is because I need to do an un-equi join. sqldf is too slow for me. So, I want to really understand this.

This answer here by @MichaelChirico is actually trying to explain what is going on under the hood: data.table join is hard to understand
Using:
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x = rep(c("b", "a", "c"), each = 3),
                y = c(1, 3, 6),
                v = 1:9)
X = data.table(x = c("c", "b"),
               v = 8:7,
               foo = c(4, 2))

He says:

Note also that we are using the right table to "look up" rows of the
left table (in DT[X, on = .(x, y <= foo)]). That means we go through
the rows of X and see which rows of DT match.

This is where me saying we are working inside the scope of the left table comes from. But it doesn't explain what happens when there is no index found. Thankfully he explained that in the comment:

That case is governed by the nomatch= parameter. it will "fill out"
unmatched rows by putting missing for all the DT columns. that's like
x=1:10; x[11]: an unmatched index is requested, NA is returned.

So, when there is no match, missing values for the DT columns are returned, and the non-missing values for the X columns are kept.
But what about A[B, on = 'a', bb := i.b], what happens here? The same logic as before, now we decide to update A by reference using :=. If there are duplicate indeces returned (because there are multiple matches in on), := chooses the last matched index. If there is no-match for an index i.b will just set to NA. So, this is not really A left join B, because there can't be more rows in the result than the amount of rows from A.

You sharing examples from other people and assuming a take on them is only driving your misunderstanding further. Like Gregor mentioned, just use merge() and stop confusing yourself with data.table() joins.

@stefan_aus_hannover if you read through the answer you will probably understand it as well. Who is confused?

You're actually doing a right outer join with that code. If you swap A and B in your code you can tell the difference.
A <- data.table::data.table("a"=1:4, "b"=12:15)
B <- data.table::data.table("a"=2:3, "b"=13:14)
A[B, on='a']

       a     b   i.b
   <int> <int> <int>
1:     2    13    13
2:     3    14    14

This link will explain it more (if it stays active later on down the road past 2024)
R joins
You are appending the outer data table to the inner data table. Thus in your example you are matching the rows from B to A. Thats why you end up with NAs in A after the join. My example shows that reverse that you are only bring the two rows from A that match in B.

why are you calling it a right outer join and everybody else a left join?

@Helen it all depends how you want to define left and right in this notation. left_join(A, B) is the same as right_join(B, A). In data.table A[B, on='a'] is a left outer join of B to A, or equivalently a right outer join of A to B.

@GregorThomas Yes, so if we define A[B, on='a'] as a left join of B to A, then we all know what we need. I know that left_join(A, B) is the same as right_join(B, A), I just don't see the point of this answer telling me that "Hey this is really a right outer join". It does not explain what is really happening, step by step, in the A[B, on='a'] join

It still seems to me like the root of your confusion was that you assumed A[B, on='a'] was a left join of A to B, which this answer also tries to correct.

@gregorthomas and how did you /others end up with that conclusion?

@Helen did you read  through the article I linked where it describes the join? Gregor isn't one the challenge on the R language.

@Helen because in your question you did B[A, on='a'] and got the result of left_join(A, B) (or equivalently right_join(B, A), and then said "But I just don't understand what happens when there is no match. Why would we "bring" a row from A (first and last row)", which implies that you didn't understand that B[A, on='a'] is equivalent to left_join(A, B), because that "'bring' a row from A" is exactly what a left join starting with A would do...

The other possibility is that you don't know what a left join is at all but you stated "I understand SQL and all these types of joins." Which suggests the problem is the syntax.

@gregorthomas ok, only two possibilities, you narrowed it down, and there is no other possibilities.

Well, those are the two that seemed most likely to me.
